# How to make a TextView reduce its width if text is wrapped and moved to next line?

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

In a TextView, when there the length of the word is greater than the width can accommodate, it wraps the text and moves it to the next line. However, the TextView doesn't wrap its own width even though there is empty space to the right.

How can I make the TextView reduce its width when it's wrapping the text?

[image: TextView not wrapping width]

Here's the TextView :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userMessageTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_design"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="some text"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

And, textview_design.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/chat_message_text_corner_radius" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Are you using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`?

Comment: make your `android:layout_width=wrap_content` in your xml for `textView`

Comment: show your xml file for this textview

Comment: @user13 Yup, the layout width of the textview is wrap_content.

Comment: @Vickyexpert I've added the textview xml

Comment: what is your `textview_design` ? a drawable? an image? or 9-patch?

Comment: @abhiank as you have set background image with that round curve shape. it's width is larger and there for it will not reduce the size for wrapping to text, so for checking it just try to apply static width like 50 dp or 100 dp and then check you will get idea

Comment: @SripadRaj its a drawable xml. I've added the code to the question

Comment: @Vickyexpert but its working on other cases when the text wrapping is not happening. So I dont think its the curved background which is causing this. I even tried it without the background and its not working.

Comment: This textview is inside some recyclerview_item_row layout xml,right?can you post the xml of that file?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

As you saw in your exemple, the TextView can perfectly wrap its content when there are new lines (`\n`) to separate the content.

So the solution is simple, calculate where the new lines should be and insert them in your String !

[image]

I use the method `measureText` to calculate the width of the current text. If it's smaller than the max width I try to add some more text on the line. When it reaches the maxWidth, a new line is inserted !

```
String message = "This is a long message that will be displayed on multiple lines";
int textViewContentMaxWidth = 600; // you need to calculate that value, for me it was screenWidth - 40 dp (16dp margins on each side and 4 dp padding on each side)

String[] sections = message.split(" ");
String formattedMessage = ReplaceBreakWordByNewLines(sections, tv.getPaint(), textViewContentMaxWidth)
tv.setText(formattedMessage);
```

--

```
public static String ReplaceBreakWordByNewLines(String[] _texts, Paint _paint, int maxWidth)
{
    String formattedText = "";

    String workingText = "";
    for (String section : _texts)
    {
        String newPart = (workingText.length() > 0 ? " " : "") + section;
        workingText += newPart;

        int width = (int)_paint.measureText(workingText, 0, workingText.length());

        if (width > maxWidth)
        {
            formattedText += (formattedText.length() > 0 ? "\n" : "") + workingText.substring(0, workingText.length() - newPart.length());
            workingText = section;
        }
    }

    if (workingText.length() > 0)
        formattedText += (formattedText.length() > 0 ? "\n" : "") + workingText;

    return formattedText;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Not sure why I didnt think of this. Anyways, this problem was many projects ago and I haven't really thought about this. Is this working for you? Also, whats textViewContentMaxWidth?

Comment: Also, have you looked into this : (Part of support lib 26.0)
http://androidkt.com/autosizing-textviews/

Comment: I saw the support library. But I wanted, like you, to have a smaller textview because I didn't want to background to fill the entire space.

Comment: Yes, it works. I've added screenshots. I calculate the textViewContentMaxWidth as the screen width minus the container view margin (16dp on each side) and the TextView padding (4dp on each side).